# Can client know Node.js server has disconnected him

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

**Environment**

*Server*: Node.js
*Client*: Browser
*Communication*: Socket.io

I already handle on **server side** when a client disconnects. But I wonder, is it possible to handle a **server disconnection** on client side?

Said in other words,

suppose server enters exception state and shuts down, how can the client know this happened? Can I use the very same code

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {...});
```

on client?

Appreciate the help.

---

**Things tried**

To check if client is getting notified via

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {...});
```

I throw the following exception in the server:

```
setTimeout(function () {  
      console.log('Throwing error now.');
      throw new Error('User generated fault.');
    }, 9000);
```

In client I have:

```
socket.on('disconnect',function(data){ console.log('Server disconnected you'); } );
```

But the log message in client **never happens**. ¿?

Comment: What are you using to talk to the client? Is this a `socket.io` question?

Comment: @Jivings I fixed it in the quesiton. Yes I am using Socket.io for communication between server-client.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`socket.io client`](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket) docs:

> Events
>
> - `connect`. Fired upon connecting.
> - `disconnect`. Fired upon a disconnection.

So yes, the client works in identical manner to the server.

Comment: I thought so too, but the client never logs the message through. ¿?

Comment: limit the number of reconnection attempt socket.io tries to make. it REALLY wants you to be connected. Disconnect only occurs when it CANNOT connect.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout other socket.io client-side events. https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/exposed-events
Try to listen 'reconnect_failed' or 'error' instead of 'disconnect'.